# Cannot make crypto.js compare hashed input against an array of hashes

Tags: javascript, hash

I'm trying to make a coupon verifying form, that uses encryption in order to hide the coupons from the user.

```
<input name="coupon-code" id="coupon-code" type="text" value="fedora">
```

This is the validating function:

```
     //validated dynamically
     $("#coupon-code").on('keyup', function () {
    //stringified hash
    coupons = ["3DA8FF923121DE176A1AB9FA3609A2AEAC25623628C8EB9E2C3D0D7364131648DE8E3F86259720EDC2C761F440AEB45225945765E05D21532B413834316EDBDB" ];
    //after hashing the value of the input, convert it to a string
    hash = CryptoJS.SHA512($(this).val()).toString(CryptoJS.enc.base64);
    //loop and compare
    for (i = 0; i < coupons.length; i++) {
        if (hash == i) {
            $('#coupon-code').css("background-color", "green");
        } else {
            $('#coupon-code').css("background-color", "red");
        }
    }
});
```

I've kept the "true" coupons instead of the hashes in the array for demo purposes.

The first problem is I cannot get `crypto` to compare the input to an element in the array:

```
CryptoJS.SHA512($("#coupon-code").val()) == CryptoJS.SHA512("fedora");

false
```

Another concern is that the user can see the encryption algorithm (SHA 512 in this case) and could reverse-hash the coupon in the array. `Crypto.js` hasn't asked/provided me a key, so I'd imagine it would be easy.

Comment: You can't "reverse" SHA512. The main problem is that you're trusting the user's browser to determine whether or not a user has entered a valid code.

Comment: Should I validate on the server?

Comment: Compare the strings. If their hashes aren't the same then it is highly likely that the strings are different. To correct that you need to determine exactly how they are different.

Comment: comparing the strings works but I'll have to ditch this approach and validate server-side instead.

Comment: @StevensHaen: Definitely.